# Why Can't ArcPy Search the Newly Created Feature

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, cache

I'm running the following tool in ArcGIS 10. I have an ArcPy Script like this:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
env.workspace=r"C:/sde/lcimrl.sde"
fc="SDE.ATTACHMENTS\SDE.attachment_points"
fcRows = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc, "OBJECTID = 11365")
for row in fcRows: 
   print "I found one"
```

The feature with OBJECTID 11365 is just created.

It can find the feature if I run it as standalone script. But when I run it in the ArcMap's interactive python window or import it into a ArcTool toolbox and then run it, it cannot find the feature.

I have to force the refresh of the SDE connection in the ArcCatalog, and then I can get the point. Or I have to wait for a while, like several hours, then it can find the point.

I tried `arcpy.ClearWorkspaceCache_management(`) and `arcpy.refreshTOC()`. They do not help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: i get several errors using the interactive python shell in Arcmap, my advice is to use PyScripter.

Comment: I have to publish it as a geoprocessing service. So I need to test it in the toolbox first, but I got this issue. I use the interactive python window only to confirm the issue.

Comment: You are using raw notation in this section r"C:/sde/lcimrl.sde" but that normally means that you need backslashes.  perhaps remove the r from the line or replace / with \  and see if that is the issue.

Comment: tried to remove the r, no help.

Comment: The r would not be the problem.  It automatically escapes the forward slashes and is a standard way to make paths safe on Windows.  Clutching at straws here but did you save/commit your new feature before searching for it?  If not, it wont 'exist'.

Comment: It is saved and committed on another PC/or by another person. I have to refresh the SDE connection first on my PC to get the new feature. seems the SDE connection cached something. I tried to refresh the SDE workspace in ArcPy. Not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I read this right, it sounds like you are a bit familiar with arcpy refresh issues. I believe you will be able to get by this if you use

`arcpy.RefreshCatalog()`

[arcpy.RefreshCatalog documentation](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000004z000000)